# It's a find-a-movie challenge

Tags: code-golf, internet

This is a simple(ish) web scraping challenge.

**Input**

Your code should take [an MPAA film rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_of_America_film_rating_system) and a number from 0 to 100 as input. It can do this in any way you find convenient.

**Output**

Your code should return the name of any movie which has a) that film rating and b) the numerical score on the Tomatometer from [rottentomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/).

If there is no such movie it can output anything you like.

The possible MPAA film ratings are `G, PG, PG-13, R, NC-17, NR`.

Your code may report one or more movies, that is up to you.

To clarify, your code is meant to access the web to get the answers to queries.

**Example**

Say the input is "PG, 98" then your code could output "Zootropolis".

Please show an example of your code working with the film rating `PG` and score `98` along with your answer.

Comment: O_O NC-17 sounds bad

Comment: NC-17, unlike the others, is *supposed* to be inappropriate. :P

Comment: Should my answer return more than one movie?

Comment: @BlackCap Edited the question.  That's up to you.

Comment: Zootropolis or Zootopia?

Comment: @BlackCap They are the same movie I believe just renamed for different countries.

Comment: This challenge should be edited so the answer isn't a simple web request to the rottentomatoes API.

Comment: @Tom  I think the current answerers wouldn't like that. But it's not quite a simple web request currently, there is json to parse (or grep).

Comment: Would it break a rule if someone created a `goo.gl` link to decrease the link address size?

Comment: @RobertBenson [Yes.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10166/68615)

Comment: `PG-13` doesn't seem to appear in the API, only `PG13` does. Consider changing your question to account for that.

Comment: I'll be saving some of the answers to help when I can't pick a movie...fun puzzle!

Comment: I'm not sure where people have found this API address, but as best as I can tell, this challenge seems to go against the policies of Fandango (the owner of rottentomatoes) as can be viewed [here](https://developer.fandango.com/Rotten_Tomatoes) and from their ToS linked from there.

Comment: In looking into the API's JSON, I have discovered that it will, by default, only return 32 results at at a time. There are however 123 films (as of this writing) with a score of 98 (for example) meaning that there is a possibility that, although films might exist with the given score and rating, they may not be returned in those 32. More results *can* be requested using the `limit` parameter but the maximum is 876 and there are currently 1315 films with a score of 100 (for example) - the other 439 can be retrieved by adding the `page` parameter.

Comment: Does this information invalidate all answers, including my own?

Comment: @Shaggy Only if you can find a case where your code doesn't give the right answer in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Stratos](https://github.com/okx-code/Stratos/), 133 bytes

```
{
f"www.rottentomatoes.com/api/private/v2.0/browse?minTomato=%&maxTomato=%&type=dvd-streaming-all"r"results")s"mpaaRating"=⁰
s"title"
```

[Try it!](http://okx.sh/stratos/?code=%7B%0Af%22rottentomatoes.com%2Fapi%2Fprivate%2Fv2.0%2Fbrowse%3FminTomato%3D%25%26maxTomato%3D%25%26type%3Ddvd-streaming-all%22r%22results%22)s%22mpaaRating%22%3D%E2%81%B0%0As%22title%22%0A&input=98%0APG)

Comment: Could you show an example of your code being used please.

Comment: @Lembik Well, run it, and type in the number, press enter, type in the rating, press enter, and it will give you the output.

Comment: Can you drop the `www.`?

Comment: @Shaggy Unfortunately not.

Comment: Maybe you could just post a screenshot of it running?

Comment: @Lembik Added a link.

Comment: Stratos specializes in web challenges

Answer (score 12):

## Bash, 182 bytes

```bash
curl "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/api/private/v2.0/browse?minTomato=$2&maxTomato=$2&type=dvd-streaming-all" 2>/dev/null|grep -o "{[^}]*aRating\":\"$1\""|grep -Po 'title":"\K[^"]*'
```

Usage:

```bash
$ bash script PG 98
The Island President
Inside Out
Zootopia
Paddington
Love & Friendship
Long Way North (Tout en haut du monde)
```

Comment: I really like this answer.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>167</s> <s>162</s> 159 bytes

[Needs to be run from the root of rottentomatoes.com](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13621/58974). [Returns a `Promise` object](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12327/58974) containing the title.

```js
s=>n=>fetch(`api/private/v2.0/browse?minTomato=${n}&maxTomato=${n}&type=dvd-streaming-all`).then(r=>r.json()).then(j=>j.results.find(x=>x.mpaaRating==s).title)
```

If we can [require that it be run in a specific directory](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13938/58974) then it becomes 139 bytes:

```js
s=>n=>fetch(`browse?minTomato=${n}&maxTomato=${n}&type=dvd-streaming-all`).then(r=>r.json()).then(j=>j.results.find(x=>x.mpaaRating==s).title)
```

Comment: It would be great if there were a click and look way to test Javascript answers.

Comment: @Lembik: normally that can be done when working with APIs but, in this case, RT's CORS policy prevents it. Thanks for the accept, by the way.

Comment: Hmm..I just noticed there are shorter answers but I don't have the energy/expertise to test Stratos code right now. If I do, I will have to change the accept, sorry.

Comment: @Lembik: I fully expected Stratos to get it (so far).

Comment: Oh I added a bounty to the other find-a-movie question :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) + requests, <s>209</s> 204 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to Ian Gödel.*

```python
lambda r,t:[i['title']for i in get('http://rottentomatoes.com/api/private/v2.0/browse?minTomato=%d&maxTomato=%d&type=dvd-streaming-all'%(t,t)).json()['results']if i['mpaaRating']==r]
from requests import*
```

Comment: Think you may need (t,t) where you have (r,r)

Comment: You can use this link: `http://rottentomatoes.com/api/private/v2.0/browse?minTomato=%d&maxTomato=%d&type=dvd-streaming-all` (`https` -> `http` and drop the `www.`) for [a couple of bytes saved](https://tio.run/##Rc6xTsMwFEbhnafwUpygNEYVYqgU8Q6ILfJwS25aV7avuf4b6NOHiIXxSN9wyh0XyYd1jZROExntcBzDaBEQ2fpZ1AQTsjkzGnsBytE5FYAzJBGEa/8pyVEJrmhYCOyWQ//sTirfld9SyB9/bthNj4l@/gP3wsO0TPsKZdrceU8x2l2DDm3bX6vkph2tcr1FVOvDbLatVIjeCZu2fhjUP8wqySh/3biimpCKKJ7WdXztXvwv).

Comment: Could you show an example of your code being used please.

Answer (score 2):

## [q/kdb+](http://kx.com/download/), 168 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{(r(&)(r:.j.k[.Q.hg`$"https://www.rottentomatoes.com/api/private/v2.0/browse?type=dvd-streaming-all&min",t,"&max",t:"Tomato=",y]`results)[;`mpaaRating]like x)[;`title]}
```

**Example:**

```
q){(r(&)(r:.j.k[.Q.hg`$"https://www.rottentomatoes.com/api/private/v2.0/browse?type=dvd-streaming-all&min",t,"&max",t:"Tomato=",y]`results)[;`mpaaRating]like x)[;`title]}["PG";"98"]
"The Island President"
"Inside Out"
"Zootopia"
"Paddington"
"Love & Friendship"
"Long Way North (Tout en haut du monde)"
```

**Explanation:**

```
.Q.hg           / fetch a URL
.j.k            / parse json string into Q dictionaries
`results        / index into dictionary with key `results
[;`mpaaRating]  / index into these sub dictionaries extracting mpaaRating
like x          / binary list where they match, e.g. "PG"
(&)             / where, list indices where true
[;`title]       / index into dictionary with key `title
```

**Notes:**

- If you want to try this out yourself, take a read through the [Cookbook/SSL](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Cookbook/SSL) page to ensure your environment is setup correctly.
- Fails if we remove the `s` of `https`, or the `www.`, gives `301 Permanently Moved` response.

Comment: Maybe add a link for "q/kdb+" in the title of your answer? A lot of people will never have heard of it and you can educate them (me).

Comment: Done :) I was hoping to write a solution in oK but getting a 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present...' when using the online repl (http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/index.html), so have falled back to the closed-source Q.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES2017), 158 bytes

```
async(r,n)=>(await(await fetch(`api/private/v2.0/browse?minTomato=${n}&maxTomato=${n}&type=dvd-streaming-all`)).json()).results.find(m=>m.mpaaRating==r).title
```

Run from the [Rotten Tomatoes home page](https://rottentomatoes.com):

```
f=async(r,n)=>(await fetch(`api/private/v2.0/browse?minTomato=${n}&maxTomato=${n}&type=dvd-streaming-all`).then(x=>x.json())).results.find(m=>m.mpaaRating==r).title
f('PG',98).then(console.log)
```