# A British find-a-movie challenge

Tags: code-golf, internet

This is a more difficult version of  [It's a find-a-movie challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/143772/its-a-find-a-movie-challenge) .

**Input**

Your code should take [a BBFC rating](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/content-ratings/BBFC) and a number from 1 to 5 as input. It can do this in any way you find convenient.

**Output**

Your code should return the name of any movie which has a) that film rating and b) that number of stars in a [Guardian film review](https://www.theguardian.com/film+tone/reviews).

If there is no such movie it can output anything you like.

The possible BBFC film ratings are `U, PG, 12, 12A, 15, 18, R18, TBC`.

Your code may report one or more movies, that is up to you.

To clarify, your code is meant to access the web to get the answers to queries.

**Example**

Say the input is `U, 5` then your code could output "My Neighbour Totoro".

Please show an example of your code working with the film rating `PG` and score `4` along with your answer.

**Notes**

The Guardian does have an API but this requires registration.  For this challenge you may not use it.

**Example code**

The following Python 3 code gets all the movies along with their score out of 5, although not 100% perfectly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys

for i in range(1,837):
    print("Page", i,file=sys.stderr)
    result = requests.get("https://www.theguardian.com/film+tone/reviews?page={0}".format(i))
    data = result.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

    tags = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"stars"})

    for tag in tags:
        stars = 0
        for star in tag.find_all("span", {"class":"star__item--grey"}):
            stars +=1
        main = tag.parent
        title = main.find("h2")
        if title:
            a = title.find("span", {"class":"js-headline-text"})
            print("{} - {}".format(5 - stars, a.text))
```

Answer (score 3):

## NodeJS

I'm an awful golfer tho

The inputs must be passed like this `node filename 12,12A,15,18 4` for fetching a movie with one of the ratings comma separated and at least 4 stars

```
var fetch=require('node-fetch');
var {JSDOM, VirtualConsole}=require('jsdom');

var f=x=>fetch(x).then(r=>r.text());
var vc = new VirtualConsole(); // ignore annoying css errors
var [bbfc='U,PG,12',stars='3']=process.argv.slice(2);

var Z=async()=>{
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){ // 10 max pages, can be anything
        var t= await f(`https://www.theguardian.com/film+tone/reviews?page=${i}`);
        var w=new JSDOM(t, {virtualConsole:vc}).window;
        for(var h of w.document.querySelectorAll('.fc-item__header')){
            if (h.querySelectorAll('.star__item--golden').length>=stars){
                var title=h.querySelector('.js-headline-text').textContent.split(' review')[0].trim();
                var t=await f('http://www.bbfc.co.uk/search/releases/'+title);
                var rating=t.match(/BBF\w_(\w+)_/)[1];
                if(bbfc.includes(rating)) return title;
            }
        }
    }
};

Z()
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error)
```

Comment: At least you can remove lots of unnecessary whitespaces, and you must also include the bytecount.

Comment: That's 956 bytes, but removing whitespaces  could save you some.

Comment: It works! However the question asks for exactly the right score, not at least the score.

Comment: I found a bug I think. Try `node caub.js U 4`.  You get `Peter Bradshaw's film of the week  Daphne`. First, Daphne is rated 15 and second you need to extract the movie name.

Comment: The code crashes on page 28 with TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at Z (/home/foo/caub.js:17:51)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

Comment: On page 22, the code returns "The Florida Project" as a "U" rated movie but it isn't rated at all yet by the BBFC as far as I can tell and it's R rated in the US so it can't be right. See e.g. http://www.bbfc.co.uk/search/releases/The%2BFlorida%2BProject . I general it might give the wrong answer for movies for which the BBFC has no rating.

Comment: instead of `var variable;var variable`, use `var variable,variable,variable`. and get rid of whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript/JQuery - <s>517</s> <s>504</s> 494 bytes

Not really golfed at all, just wanted to write an answer.

```
x=>y=>{t=n=i=1;f=()=>{if(t){$.get("https://www.theguardian.com/film+tone/reviews?page="+i,d=>{l=$(d).find("div.stars").toArray().slice(1);for(k=0;k<l.length&&t;k++){((j,m)=>($.get('http://www.bbfc.co.uk/search/releases/'+encodeURI(n=$(m[j].parentNode).find("h2 span.js-headline-text").text().split(" review")[0]),(p=>b=>{if(/BBFC_(.*?)_/.exec($(b).find(".symbol img")[0].src)[1]==y&&$(m[j]).find(".star__item--golden").length==x){if(t)alert(p);t=0}})(n))))(k,l)}});i++;setTimeout(f,2000)}};f()}
```

It waits 10 sec before trying another page to stop the program from doing too many requests concurrently, so it may take some time with some inputs.

### Examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know JS, but I do know that `x=>y=>` using currying is a byte shorter than `(x,y)=>`.

Comment: Thank you for giving the first answer!  Is it possible to make a https://tio.run/# link for it?

Comment: @Lembik TIO cannot access the internet. Since this is JS, a Stack Snippet could be used, or it's reasonably easy to run the code in your browser's console.

Comment: since when jquery is allowed in golfing? use fetch

Comment: Can you show an example of your code running? I am having no luck getting it to work. My steps: open new tab, press F12, enter f=(x,y)..., f("U",5) . Then f("U",5) gives me
TypeError: $.get is not a function [Learn More]

Comment: @caub as it's included in the language of the answer, it's allowed to be used. It's the same as using libraries in other languages.

Comment: @dzaima Wasn't the complaint that it is one character longer?

Comment: @Lembik that's cuz you don't have jquery. Easiest way is to just run it in the console on http://jquery.com. Also, you'll need to disable cors if you're running it in the browser

Comment: @Lembik added examples

Answer (score 1):

## Python + BS4 - 631 bytes

Lembik wanted a Python answer so he could run it, so I made one, but its way longer.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b
import requests
def f(x,y):
 i=n=1
 while 1:
  for m in b(requests.get("https://www.theguardian.com/film+tone/reviews?page="+`i`).text,'lxml').find_all('div',{'class':'stars'}):
         a=m.parent.find('h2')
         if a:
          e=a.find('span',{'class':'js-headline-text'}).text.split(" review")[0]
          s=b(requests.get('http://www.bbfc.co.uk/search/releases/'+requests.utils.quote(e)).text,'lxml').find("p",{"class":"symbol"})
          if s and s.find("img").get('src').split("BBFC_")[1].split("_")[0]==y and len(m.find_all('span',{'class':'star__item--golden'}))==x:return e
  i+=1
```

Comment: The code crashes on page 6 with "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guardianfilm-2.py", line 17, in <module>
    print f(5, "U")
  File "guardianfilm-2.py", line 13, in f
    if s and s.find("img").get('src').split("BBFC_")[1].split("_")[0]==y and len(m.find_all('span',{'class':'star__item--golden'}))==x:
IndexError: list index out of range
"

Comment: [621 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZHdTuMwEIXv@xQj3zhR22SLuIpkIRVpX2AvVyg4ySQx@A@PA60Qz951SrtECF/OzBmf74w/xtHZm9OpD85AQ7egjHchwh7lFFU/6T9u8iAJmtWlE/BlQoq06rCHPjtsjnm1AiWs2K3gbVQaYZcK0LsABpSFJrtKigFjxsYYPVVlGUccJhk6JW3ROlP2Spt1dBbLgK8K3@jOywEFWz@qx7yIeIgbrg9G87zole1qqXXGO/XKN@@81ZKIV5yiDMQ/ZkfXJ4UpvAxo41mW8fGG519t1YNcTAMKeZkjL@1y9xNtR5SdVha3s5v0zdlVQV6rxAWftln@99fDYiGJbwHwOYCqbJq@TdzF9FwSytCOCVujJKSSr/8L0hE0FS@Ti5hh/kMMGfNs887OJlnF6Ggap9nHgnBGJJC2g6MQdBEpM7D80w6FNu26QOz3v@/rhLB7uFbqM9As12gzs8j@e0Bz@HWtIprtdnC6Q5siyoU4VAHjFCxgMqXWYnc6/QM) with a bit of reordering and link tweaking.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder You can [save a few bytes](https://tio.run/##bZDNbtswEITP0lMseKEE21Id9CSAKOACfYEei0ChpKXEln/hUomNIM/u0o5TBEGvuzuz8004pcW7u/NZRW9hoK@gbfAxwQHlmrRazU@/BpAEQ3nbRHxckRKVEypQ1XF7qrsStHBiX8Lzog3CvisL5SNY0A6G6l3RzJgqtqQUqGvbtOC8yjhp6ZrR21ZpYzfJO2wjPml8pm9BzijY5kE/1E3CY9pyc7SG143SbuqlMRWf9BPfvvDRSCLecUoyEn/NgQqQwjZBRnTpel/x5Y7Xea4VyLwvUMjbgoJ0H11@025BORntcHf5mw2v/xsKRmcCeAvI6l9f7rMRiU@I/ILYtcOgxkzWrH9aQhnHJYMZlITU8s0/QW7ZUPO4@oQV1v8BrVhg2xd2Dcc6Ric7eMNeM0qRUQikm@AkBN2OtZ1Z/RaD4pg9bqEPhx/f@xx5f/8@6a8AF7lBV9kPrX4u5FJr3@uEdrebvZnQ5UpqIY5dxLRGB1gWeiP25/Nf) by optimizing indentation.

Comment: Is the variable n used at all in your code?